# In sklearn's classification_report, what does avg/total mean? How is it computed?

Tags: scikit-learn

```
              precision    recall  f1-score   support

          0       0.98      0.90      0.94       305
          1       0.77      0.93      0.84       102
avg / total       0.92      0.91      0.91       407
```

what does avg/total mean? and how does it be computed?
didn't find answer on the official website TAT

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's either average **or** total. Average refers to the first 3: precision, recall and f1-score whereas total refers only to support.

Edit:
Just to be clear, the average refers to the **weighted** average, where each label's weight is its support.

Answer (score 2):

Let's take a look at your first column. In the third row of the column you can see that `0.92` is computed by
`0.98*(305/407) + 0.77*(102/407)`.